# Creating duplicates of specific rows of data

Tags: excel-formula

I have a report with several rows of data. One column (number column) in each row lists a random number from 1 to 99. I need to duplicate the row of data the number of times that are noted in the "number" column. Example:  John Smith gets 32 chances in a contest. The number 32 is the "number".  I need to duplicate John Smith's row of data 31 additional times so he has 32 rows. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Name your number column "rangename"

Press alt+f11. Put this in

```
Public Sub CopyForEach()
    Dim varcell as variant
    Dim iiterator as integer
    Dim icount as integer

    For Each varcell in ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("rangename")
             icount = varcell.value
             For iiterator = 1 to icount
                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(varcell.address).(1,iiterator).value = icount
             Next iiterator
    Next

End Sub
```

Press F5.

Note: not tested.